# Python regressors library summary function returns ValueError for Logistic regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, statsmodels, valueerror

I'm using python inbulit boston dataset from sklearn with CHAS as my target variable.

I built Logistic Regression model from sklearn pkg.I'm using regressors library to get the summary statistics of the model output but i'm facing the following error. pleasee help me on this and kindly let me know if you need further information

find more about regressors library in below link: [1]: 
https://regressors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

Please find the below python code which i used for model building:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
import pandas as pd

bostonn = datasets.load_boston()
boston = pd.DataFrame(bostonn.data , columns= bostonn['feature_names'])
print(boston.head())

X = boston.drop('CHAS' , axis =1)
y = boston.CHAS.astype('category')

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from regressors import stats
log_mod=LogisticRegression(random_state=123)
model=log_mod.fit(X,y)

stats.summary(model, X, y , xlabels=None)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
in ()
1 #xlabels = boston.feature_names[which_betas]
----> 2 stats.summary(model, X, y ,xlabels=None)

251     )
252     coef_df['Estimate'] = np.concatenate(
--> 253 (np.round(np.array([clf.intercept_]), 6), np.round((clf.coef_), 6)))
254 coef_df['Std. Error'] = np.round(coef_se(clf, X, y), 6)
255 coef_df['t value'] = np.round(coef_tval(clf, X, y), 4)

ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

> ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

There are other posts which has the similar error but those solution didn't help 
my problem.The attached above link has the information about how the summary function actually works.kindly let me know if you need further information.

Comment: @James Z, can u help me on this

Comment: Sorry, don't know anything about this

Comment: `LogisticRegression` is not a regressor. Its a classifier.

Comment: What is the output of `print(X.shape, y.shape)`?

Comment: @BlackBear It has nothing to do with `X, y`, but the shape of `coef_` and `intercept_`  that are learnt when the model is `fit()`. That is different in regressors and classifiers in scikit-learn and also depend on other factors. The library OP is using is about the regression models where as `LogisticRegression` (despite its name) is a classifier.

Comment: @VivekKumar I know what logistic regression is. If you read the OP's code, you would realize (s)he's trying to predict CHAS, which is a categorical variable (hence, classification).

Comment: I understand that. But the library which he is using `from regressors import stats` does not work with classifiers. Thats what I said in above comment.

Comment: LogisticRegression is a classifier, but then it is actually implemented as a regression trying to approximate the function (in the simplest case of binary classification)

    Pr[x is in class 1]

Therefore, it is in theory possible to compute all the statistical quantities you get in regression about coefficient significance, etc. 

Therefore, is there a way to get all this information with `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression`? 

Note that this information is available if you use another implementation of LogisticRegression, namely `statsmodel.Logit`